# Python setuptools entrypoints and subapplications as child processes

Tags: python, subprocess, setuptools, entry-point, pkg-resources

I'm working on Windows and developing an application that will be distributed to end users.

I have one setupttools distribution that contains a nandful of python packages. This distribution declares some console_scripts entrypoints that point to various functions in my code.

One of these entrypoints is destined to be an updater application. I currently am launching it as a child process using subprocess and specifying the full path to a python script.

What i'd like to do instead is use the generated setuptools entrypoint stub executable as the subprocess to launch.

I can get the entrypoint to my subapplication via something like:

```
import pkg_resources
updatefunc = pkg_resources.load_entry_point('iti_reporter', 'console_scripts', 'my_update_ui')
```

which gives me the python function for it. Is there any way to go from this function to the generated setuptools script wrapper that resides in my venv?

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out by just doing what the script would have done anyway:

```
def _get_entry_script(dist, entrytype, entryname):
    import pkg_resources
    mainfunc = pkg_resources.load_entry_point(dist, entrytype, entryname)
    entry_load_script = """import sys; from pkg_resources import load_entry_point;
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('%s', '%s', '%s')()
    )"""
    script = entry_load_script%(dist, entrytype, entryname)
    script = ''.join(x.strip() for x in script.split('\n') if x.strip())
    return script

def _get_updater_script_arg_dev():
    return _get_entry_script('mydist', 'console_scripts', 'mypkg_update_ui')

def launch_updater():
    cmd = (os.path.abspath(sys.executable), '-c', _get_updater_script_arg_dev(), '--arg1', '--arg2')
    return subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```